# Domino layout - overlapping boxes

Tags: math

Sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-wozniak-mci9l

I'm trying to reproduce an effect similar to the following (with a fixed spacing between each tile):

[image]

I almost have the right effect, but as you can see on the sandbox, the boxes are overlapping the further down the right they get. My maths are probably off somewhere, but I don't see where.

Here's what I thought would work:

[image]

Comment: Is this about math (and thus should be on [the math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)) or about programming (in which case you need to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and of course not forget how to create a [mcve]).

Comment: I'm not sure "how to create a minimal reproducible example" would help given that the second line is literally a minimal reproducible example. This is both about math and programming, as I don't know whether the problem comes from maths or an oversight in the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My implementation didn't take into account that the increment by which each box had to be moved wasn't the domino width, but rather a new amount defined by the following relation:

[image]

I discovered it by completely omitting the domino width from the increment, only leaving the margins: the dominos were perfectly aligned on the left side, meaning that the alignment problem on the right side could only come from the width increment.